# Invalid signature REST API Magento 2

Tags: php, rest, api, get, magento2

I'm trying to create a request to Magento 2 REST API:

```
$_method = 'GET';
$_url = 'http://host/rest/V1/categories/list/?searchCriteria[currentPage]=0';
```

I use oauth and have all tokens (consumer, consumer secret, token and token secret) but when i'm creating request then get response with error:

```
{"message":"Invalid signature"}
```

I also tried to create a query in POSTMAN and there everything is ok. I don't understand this. Where is the mistake?

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIPUE.png) works with:

```
$_method = 'GET';
$_url = 'http://host/rest/V1/products/:sku';
```

but doesn't work with:

```
$_method = 'GET';
$_url = 'http://host/rest/V1/categories/list/?searchCriteria[currentPage]=0';
```

Somebody can help me? :( Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you find the solution for this post?

Answer (score 1):

For now, the only kind-ish solution I found is to use token based auth instead of oauth

It may not be the best solution, but the issue with wrong signature is not related only with multi-dimensional arrays, but also with spaces (and maybe something else). For instance, when you have a space in the sku, then products/:sku will return same error, which makes me thinking that it's magento's internal issue.